# How to query MongoDB for a value in and array

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Can anyone help me with a Mongodb query for following

```
{[
   "_id" : ObjectId("5c92ba9d36de59bd9de063a4"),
   "StudentName" : "Robert",
   "StudentAge" : 21,
   "StudentCountryName" : "UK",
   "StudentHobby" : [
      "Teaching",
      "Photography"
   ]
}
```

Want to search students with hobby as *Teaching*.

If possible can come someone provide Spring Data MongoDB equivalent or native query is also fine which can be executed in mongodb compass

Comment: is this what you want? https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9qhCSvNpmZ

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this, I hope it work**

```
let student = await this.students.findOne({"StudentHobby":{"$in":["Teaching"]}})
```